# JS Promise: Array of requests

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, promise, jquery-deferred

I have an array of peoplePickers (component where users can choose people from the employee directory). I loop over them and make an array of requests to get information from the directory (async, returns promise). Then I want to add the picker name as a key to the userIds object (not an array on purpose!) and the info from the server as value. When logging in the console, userIds is always empty.

```
var userIds = {};
var requests = [];

peoplePickers.forEach(function (picker) {
    var infos = ...;
    requests.push(getUserInfosFromDirectory(infos).then(function (userInfos) {
        userIds[picker] = userInfos.Id;
    }));
});

$.when.apply($, requests).then(function () {
    console.log(userIds);
});
```

**Function that's called**

```
function getUserInfosFromDirectory(loginName){
    ...
    return $.ajax({
        url: ...,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: loginName,
        headers: {
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    }).then(function (data) {
        return data.userInfos
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you add the core body of `getUserInfosFromDirectory()`?

Comment: @DanielB Added it. btw: I know that I get the right data and that it is returned as I want it.

Comment: how do you "know" this? what gives you the impression that the data is returned "from" somewhere "to" somewhere else?

Comment: @JaromandaX Network panel + breakpoint at `return data.userInfos`

Comment: if the request is Cross Origin, network panel lies :p but you say `data.userInfos` you return in the `.then` is correct, so it's not a CORS issue :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the return values in the callback of the apply function. Because the requests were async, the index of the iteration changed before the result was available.

```
$.when.apply($, requests).then(function () {
    var userIds = {};
    $.each(arguments, function (i, arg) {
        var val = arg[0];
        if (!val) {
            userIds[peoplePickers[i]] = null;
        } else {
            userIds[peoplePickers[i]] = val.Id;
        }
    });
});
```